# How to create a new server using OpenStack.NET

Tags: c#, openstack, openstack-nova

I am new to OpenStack, just a few hours experience. I want to create a new machine using OpenStack.NET and this is the code that I come up with.

```
var identityUrl = "http://server:5000/v2.0";
var imageUrl = "http://server:9292";
var username = "username";
var password = "password";

var cloudId = new CloudIdentity() { Username = username, Password = password };
var cloudIdProvider = new CloudIdentityProvider(new Uri(identityUrl));

cloudIdProvider.Authenticate(cloudId);

var cloudServersProvider = new CloudServersProvider(cloudId, cloudIdProvider);

var newServer = cloudServersProvider.CreateServer("cloudServerName", "Windows Server 2012", "m1.medium");
```

`identityUrl` is the url for identity service
`imageUrl` is the url for image service

I can authenticate on `cloudIdProvider.Authenticate(cloudId);` line so I think the identity service and username/password are correct.

When I debug on `cloudServersProvider.CreateServer("cloudServerName", "Windows Server 2012", "m1.medium");`, it throws `No region was provided, the service does not provide a region-independent endpoint, and there is no default region set for the user's account.` exception which I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The Identity Service is likely failing to include information about the Compute Service endpoint, because you did not specify the tenantName and/or tenantId during authentication. The next release of the SDK will include support for specifying these as described in the preview build of the [OpenStack Authentication](http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs-master/html/1bb35d97-0c79-4e98-a2ae-6c1eef098ba7.htm) documentation. However, since the described classes do not exist in the 1.3.1.0 release, you'll need to include a copy of them in your project until 1.3.2.0 is released.

- [CloudIdentityWithProject.cs](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/Domain/CloudIdentityWithProject.cs)
- [OpenStackIdentityProvider.cs](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/Providers/OpenStackIdentityProvider.cs)
- [ProjectId.cs](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/Domain/ProjectId.cs)